# Aspnet Core Decimal binding not working on non English Culture

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core

I have an aspnet core app that runs with a non english configuration (spanish):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ......
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("es-AR"))
            ,SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("es-AR")
            }
            ,SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("es")
            }
        });

        .........
    }
```

In english a decimal number has its decimal part delimited with a dot, but in spanish a comma is used:

- 10256.35 english
- 10256,35 spanish

I have this action in a controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public decimal Test(decimal val)
 {
     return val;
 }
```

If I use postman and send to that action a json like this {val: 15.30}, then val in the action recives a 0 (binding not working because of the culture). If I send a json like this {val: 15,30} then in the action I recive 15.30
The problem I have is, I need the action to accept decimals with commas, because that is the format that comes from inputs type text in the app's forms. But i also need to accept decimal with a dot that comes from request in json format.  There is no way to specify a decimal/float in json that accepts a comma (send it as string is not an option). How can I do this??? I'm driving my self crazy with this.

Thanks!!

Comment: You would need to create a custom ModelBinder that reads the `contentType` and parse the value depending on the content type

Comment: in MVC5 I used a custom model binder and it solved my issue, for mvc core you may find similar solution here [Custom Model Binding in ASP.Net Core 1.0 (RTM)](http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/)

Answer (score 22):

Apparently, the decimal binding in ASP.NET core 1.0.0 is not culture invariant by default. The model binding depends on the server culture.

You can change this behavior with a custom model binding as suggested by Stephen Muecke. Here is mine based on [Custom Model Binding in ASP.Net Core 1.0 (RTM)](http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/)

```
public class InvariantDecimalModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (!context.Metadata.IsComplexType && (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(decimal) || context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(decimal?)))
        {
            return new InvariantDecimalModelBinder(context.Metadata.ModelType);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class InvariantDecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly SimpleTypeModelBinder _baseBinder;

    public InvariantDecimalModelBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        _baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(modelType);
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            decimal result;

            // Use invariant culture
            if (decimal.TryParse(valueAsString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        // If we haven't handled it, then we'll let the base SimpleTypeModelBinder handle it
        return _baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new InvariantDecimalModelBinderProvider());
});
```

Comment: Just remark for others, this copy / paste will stop binding negative numbers. To avoid that in decimal.TryParse add also numberStyles.AllowLeadingSign for styles. Thanx a lot

Comment: Edited to add NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign. Good catch @adopilot

Comment: @LucGauthier this works only for basic type. Any way we can implement this for classes with decimal properties?

Comment: @Ruchan I didn't have the chance to test this case.