# Asp.net core 2.0 comma and point decimal separator

Tags: asp.net

I tried to make an attempt of a basic project Core 2 with just a model:

```
public class Bilance 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    [Required] 
    public decimal Amount{ get; set; } // (sql 18,2) 
}
```

I used this Custom Model Binding to use the comma as decimal seperator but it doesn't work.
([Aspnet Core Decimal binding not working on non English Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737607/aspnet-core-decimal-binding-not-working-on-non-english-culture))

Works with a few numbers (123,456) with others no (11,50... 1520,77)

Could you help me? 
Thanks